# How to know MSSql Server is installed or not in windows XP or 7?

Tags: c++, sql-server, windows, mfc

Before going to install MSSQLSERVER, I want to know whether MSSQLSERVER is already installed in the system or not. This should be done programatically in C++ or mfc.

If the MSSQLServer is already installed in the windows then Is there any possible way to get the MSSql Credentials of that server?

If So, Please Explain the way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I tried to install sqlserver 2005 and sql server 2008 in my system but both the servers are installed. I checked the registry path but It contains `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90` for `MSSQLServer 2005` and `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100` for `MSSqlServer 2008`.Before installing my MSSQLServer How can I check whether any of the MSSql Server version is installed or not?

**EDIT**

Till Now I silent installed the SQLSERVER programmatically in c++.

I Posted the code below:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo;
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = NULL;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpFile = L"D:\\Softies\\SQLEXPR.EXE";
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = L"/qn addlocal=all InstanceName=SQLEXPRESS DisableNetworkProtocols=0 SECURITYMODE=SQL SAPWD=root SQLAUTOSTART=1 SQLBROWSERAUTOSTART=1 ENABLERANU=0";
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_MAXIMIZE;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);

int nResult=0;
nResult = (int )ShExecInfo.hInstApp;
if( nResult >32) 
cout<<"EXE executed successfully"<<endl;
else
cout<<"Reason for failure is" <<nResult<<endl;
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You cannot get the server's credentials, except of brute force

**BUT**

If you're a local administrator - you can start sql server from the command line with startup key -f and try to play with it - it is not guaranteed, but you can try.

- I have a code which checks the some defaults for sql server instance, so it can be easily adopted to your needs and c++/

  ```
  private void GetSqlDefaultInfo(string ServerName, string InstanceName)
  {

      InstanceName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(InstanceName) ? "MSSQLSERVER" : InstanceName;

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ServerName))
          ServerName = Environment.MachineName;
      using (var registryKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, ServerName))
      {
          object sqlInstance;
          using (var subKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"))
              sqlInstance = subKey.GetValue(InstanceName);
          if (sqlInstance != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlInstance.ToString()))
          {
              var sqlPathKey = string.Format(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\{0}\MSSQLServer",
                                             sqlInstance);
              object defaultData, defaultLog, backupDirectory, sqlPath;
              using (var subKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(sqlPathKey))
              {
                  defaultData = subKey.GetValue("DefaultData");
                  defaultLog = subKey.GetValue("DefaultLog");
                  backupDirectory = subKey.GetValue("BackupDirectory");
              }
              sqlPathKey = string.Format(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\{0}\Setup", sqlInstance);

              using (var subKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(sqlPathKey))
                  sqlPath = subKey.GetValue("SQLDataRoot");
              DataFilePath = defaultData != null
                                 ? defaultData.ToString()
                                 : Path.Combine(sqlPath.ToString(), "Data").TrimEnd('\\');

              LogFilePath = defaultLog != null
                                ? defaultLog.ToString()
                                : Path.Combine(sqlPath.ToString(), "Data").TrimEnd('\\');
              FTSIndexFilePath = DataFilePath;
              ContentFilePath = DataFilePath;
              BackupFilePath = backupDirectory != null
                                   ? backupDirectory.ToString()
                                   : Path.Combine(sqlPath.ToString(), "Backup").TrimEnd('\\');
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: @ Oleg: I tried to install sqlserver 2005 and sql server 2008 in my system but both the servers are installed. I checked the registry path but it contains SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90 for SQLServer 2005 and SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100 for SqlServer 2008.How can I check whether any of the Sql Server version is installed or not?

Comment: @ Oleg: To see Clearly ,check the update part in my question.

Comment: @karthik you need not to check 90 or 100 (these are versions, NOT instances) - you need to check MSSQLSERVER (or MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER - depends on version) - for default instance, or InstanceName for \InstanceName instance. If you setup SQLEXPRESS instance then registry key to check is SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: @karthik You can find installed instance names in key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL, and then use them as input to other keys